# Groovy script to return mongodb distinct values

Tags: groovy

I'm using Pentaho Report Designer with Groovy scripts to build reports. I have been able to return data and utilize sort with parameters. The part I'm stumped on is the distinct to buld my parameters list dynamically instead of manually. I can run a limit after the find query but additional docs will add additional distinct values.

This is the limit I use with groovy:
         Code:

```
    def columnNames = ["<columnName"] as String[]
    def columnTypes = [String.class] as Class[]

    TypedTableModel model = new TypedTableModel(columnNames, columnTypes);

    def docs = meter.find(new BasicDBObject("<name>", "<value>")).limit(26)
    while (docs.hasNext()) {
    def doc = docs.next()
    model.addRow([ doc.get("<name>").getString("<sub_docname>")] as Object[]);
    }
    docs.close()
```

I tried to add distinct to get unique values instead of find but receive the error regarding hasNext
        No signature of method: com.mongodb.BasicDBList.hasNext()
        Code:

```
    def docs = meter.distinct("<name.subdocname>")
    while (docs.hasNext()) {
    def doc = docs.next()
    model.addRow([ doc.get("<name>").getString("<subdocname>")] as Object[]);
    }
   docs.close()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Model at the end provides a table model to put results into. Does docs.each provide some type of unique return? Unexpected token for docs.each. I think I need to change the find to include some type of unique argument. In pymongo I can just add .distinct at the end of the find but apparently not in groovy. Remember I'm limited by what Pentaho can do as well but 'm dependent on the Mongo driver.